# Reading large Xml files downloaded from a zip and loaded into MemoryStream

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, memorystream, xelement

I am reading very large Xml files (400+ MB), 15 MB zipped that is downloaded and unzipped into `MemoryStream`.  I am running into a `System.OutOfMemoryException` every time.  I tried using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` and read it to a string, doesn't work.

I googled around and am using `XmlReader` and loading it into `XElement` as suggested by posts here.  However, I am still running into the `OutOfMemoryException` error.

```
string downloadUrl = requestStatus.ReportDownloadUrl;

//create a network stream to the report Url
using (Stream reportZipStream = new WebClient().OpenRead(downloadUrl)) //download the file
using (Stream reportZipMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) //initilize zip memorystream
using (Stream reportXmlStream = new MemoryStream()) //load xml file to memorystream for manipulation
{
    //copy zip file to memorystream
    reportZipStream.CopyTo(reportZipMemoryStream);
    reportZipMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //unzip to Xml memory stream
    using (ZipFile reportZip = ZipFile.Read(reportZipMemoryStream))
    {
        reportZip[0].Extract(reportXmlStream);
    }

    reportXmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Dictionary<string, object> parsedXml = default(Dictionary<string, object>);

    //read and parse
    if (reportXmlStream.CanRead && reportXmlStream.Length > 0)
    {
        XmlDataParser parser = new XmlDataParser();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(reportXmlStream))
        {
            XElement elem = XElement.Load(reader); //out of memory error here
            parsedXml = parser.doParse(elem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `XElement.Load` will load the entire url/stream, so you know.

Comment: Closed as duplicate on how to process large xml files in C#.

Comment: How much RAM on the machine?  Is the machine  64bit?

Comment: My machne is 4GB 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You should not use DOM Parser (such XElement) for 400 Mo XML Files. You should use SAX parsers.

Comment: And why not use the one that - ouch - is in the .NET framework already? Ignorance or a real reason?

Comment: Ignorance.  I am new.  What library is in the .NET already?